# HtmlUnit stops JavaScript execution after a window.open

Tags: java, javascript, htmlunit

I've recently updated from HTMLUnit 2.4 to 2.5 (we'd go for the latest version but there is a lot of code to refactor due to the deprecated APIs).  I'm now having a problem with some JavaScript that opens a window.

The page under test, is a 'Please wait while loading screen' for reports.  The page opens a new window then redirects back to page that originally launched the print.

So the JavaScript looks something like:

```
window.open(url,'report_window');
document.location.href  = original_url;
```

With HtmlUnit 2.4 the script would continue executing and if I grabbed the original Window object it would have performed the redirect.   However, after upgrading to HtmlUnit 2.5, the original window is still on the 'Please wait' page - the redirect is never executed.   It appears as though the JavaScript stopped executing after the call to window.open.

I have confirmed the page behaves correctly if I test manually.  I've also tried different JavaScript after the window.open call to confirm that that particular call is not the issue.

Is anyone aware of an issue like this and any potential workarounds?  We have to stay on HtmlUnit 2.5 because of jQuery compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by removing the CurrentWindowTracker object from the web window listeners on the WebClient object.  Unfortunately, this field is completely encapsulated, so I had to retrieve it via reflection.

```
        Field windowListeners = WebClient.class
                .getDeclaredField("webWindowListeners_");
        windowListeners.setAccessible(true);
        Collection webWindowListeners = (Collection) windowListeners
                .get(webClient);
        webWindowListeners.clear();
```